# Como guardar valores correctamente

Tags: c#, sql, tablas

Estoy programando en C# un sistema de consultorio medico, tengo 2 objetos "Servicio" y "Producto".
En un servicio se puede usar mas de un mismo producto, por ejemplo, 2 tapabocas...

En SQL Tengo 3 tablas:

- Tabla Servicio
- Tabla Producto
- Tabla ProductosUsadosEnServicios (aquí guardo el listado de productos usados en un servicio)

El problema es que no estoy logrando descifrar como guardar la cantidad de un mismo producto que se utilizan en un solo servicio.

Se les ocurre alguna solucion al respecto
Si necesitan mas informacion me lo indican.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Con un campo `cantidad`

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se debe hacer antes de pasar a programar es construir una base de  datos que de solución al problema planteado.

1. creamos la base de datos SQL. En este caso uso MYSQL, pero la estructura no cambia mucho a si vas a usar SQL SERVER U OTRO.

> ```
> -- CREACION DE LA BASE DE DATOS --
> CREATE DATABASE consultorio;
> USE consultorio;
> ```

2. Como buena práctica siempre procura crear una tabla para usuarios, que en este caso consumen productos.

> ```
> create table usuario(  
> id_usuario int  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
> usuario_nombre varchar(50),  
> usuario_apellido varchar(50)  
> );
> ```

3. Creo la tabla más importante, la de producto, que es donde identifico los productos a controlar. el Id del producto y nombre del producto.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE producto (   
> id_producto int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,   
> producto_nombre varchar(50)
> );
> ```

4. Creo la tabla de servicios a los cuales cada registro se asocia con el consumo de uno o varios productos asociados a la prestación de los mismos.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE servicio (
> id_servicio int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
> servicio_nombre varchar(50)
> );
> ```

5. Creo la tabla de asociación, que nos va a permitir llevar un registro de que producto fue consumido, cuantas veces fue consumido, asociado a que servicio y por quien.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE productosusadosenservicios (   
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,   
> usuario_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
> servicio_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
> producto_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
> cantidad int(11)   
> );
> ```

6. Defino cuales son las llaves foráneas a usar en todo el proyecto a nivel de datos.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE productosusadosenservicios
> ADD KEY usuario_id(usuario_id),
> ADD KEY producto_id(producto_id),
> ADD KEY servicio_id(servicio_id);
> ```

7. Ahora si puedo relacionar las llaves primarias y foráneas.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE productosusadosenservicios    
> ADD CONSTRAINT productosusadosenservicios_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (producto_id) REFERENCES producto (id_producto) ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
> ADD CONSTRAINT productosusadosenservicios_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario (id_usuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
> ADD CONSTRAINT productosusadosenservicios_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (servicio_id) REFERENCES servicio (id_servicio) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
> ```

8. Luego de ello, se puede empezar a poblar las tablas en orden lógico.
   No se puede sacar nada de una caja que está vacía.

> ```
> INSERT INTO usuario (   
> id_usuario,    
> usuario_nombre,    
> usuario_apellido   
> ) VALUES(   
> 1, 'oscar', 'gonzalez'),   
> (2, 'martha', 'peña');
>
> INSERT INTO servicio (id_servicio, servicio_nombre) VALUES   
> (1, 'Consulta general'),   
> (2, 'Consulta especialista');   
>
> INSERT INTO producto (id_producto, producto_nombre) VALUES   
> (1, 'cita por primera vez'),   
> (2, 'cita de control'),   
> (3, 'ingreso a hospitalizacion'),   
> (4, 'salida de hospitalizacion'),   
> (5, 'tapabocas');   
>
> INSERT INTO productosusadosenservicios (   
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,   
> usuario_id,   
> servicio_id,    
> producto_id,   
> cantidad   
> ) VALUES (   
> 1, 1, 2, 1, 1),   
> (2, 1, 2, 2, 5),   
> (3, 1, 2, 3, 1),   
> (4, 1, 2, 4, 1),   
> (5, 2, 1, 1, 1),   
> (6, 2, 1, 2, 1),   
> (7, 2, 2, 1, 1),   
> (8, 2, 2, 2, 4),   
> (9, 1, 1, 5, 1),   
> (10, 2, 1, 5, 2),   
> (11, 2, 2, 5, 3),   
> (12, 1, 2, 5, 5);
> ```

9. Ya pobladas todas las tablas, ahí si se puede consultar la base de datos para saber si da respuesta a lo que necesitamos desarrollar.

> ```
> -- TODA LA DATA DISPONIBLE --
> SELECT
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,
> usuario.id_usuario,
> usuario.usuario_nombre,
> usuario.usuario_apellido,
> servicio.servicio_nombre,
> producto.producto_nombre,
> productosusadosenservicios.cantidad
> FROM productosusadosenservicios, servicio, producto, usuario
> WHERE productosusadosenservicios.usuario_id = usuario.id_usuario 
> AND productosusadosenservicios.servicio_id = servicio.id_servicio
> AND productosusadosenservicios.producto_id = producto.id_producto;
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> -- CONSULTA DE MEDICINA GENERAL --
> SELECT
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,
> usuario.id_usuario,
> usuario.usuario_nombre,
> usuario.usuario_apellido,
> servicio.servicio_nombre,
> producto.producto_nombre,
> productosusadosenservicios.cantidad
> FROM productosusadosenservicios, servicio, producto, usuario
> WHERE productosusadosenservicios.usuario_id = usuario.id_usuario 
> AND productosusadosenservicios.servicio_id = servicio.id_servicio
> AND productosusadosenservicios.producto_id = producto.id_producto
> AND servicio.id_servicio = 1;
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> -- CONSULTA CON ESPECIALISTAS --
> SELECT
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,
> usuario.id_usuario,
> usuario.usuario_nombre,
> usuario.usuario_apellido,
> servicio.servicio_nombre,
> producto.producto_nombre,
> productosusadosenservicios.cantidad
> FROM productosusadosenservicios, servicio, producto, usuario
> WHERE productosusadosenservicios.usuario_id = usuario.id_usuario 
> AND productosusadosenservicios.servicio_id = servicio.id_servicio
> AND productosusadosenservicios.producto_id = producto.id_producto
> AND servicio.id_servicio = 2;
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> -- Consumo de tapabocas en Consulta general --
> SELECT
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,
> usuario.id_usuario,
> usuario.usuario_nombre,
> usuario.usuario_apellido,
> servicio.servicio_nombre,
> producto.producto_nombre,
> productosusadosenservicios.cantidad
> FROM productosusadosenservicios, servicio, producto, usuario
> WHERE productosusadosenservicios.usuario_id = usuario.id_usuario 
> AND productosusadosenservicios.servicio_id = servicio.id_servicio
> AND productosusadosenservicios.producto_id = producto.id_producto
> and servicio.servicio_nombre like "%Consulta general%"
> and producto.producto_nombre like "%tapabocas%";
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> -- Consumo de tapabocas en Consulta especialista --
> SELECT
> id_ProductosUsadosEnServicios,
> usuario.id_usuario,
> usuario.usuario_nombre,
> usuario.usuario_apellido,
> servicio.servicio_nombre,
> producto.producto_nombre,
> productosusadosenservicios.cantidad
> FROM productosusadosenservicios, servicio, producto, usuario
> WHERE productosusadosenservicios.usuario_id = usuario.id_usuario    
> AND productosusadosenservicios.servicio_id = servicio.id_servicio   
> AND productosusadosenservicios.producto_id = producto.id_producto    
> and servicio.servicio_nombre like "%Consulta especialista%"    
> and producto.producto_nombre like "%tapabocas%";
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya el resto es hacer código.

Recomendación:
Debes tener muy claro cuál es el modelo de negocio del cliente.
Cuales son sus deseos y prioridades y de acuerdo a ello, trabajas.
Siempre has todas las preguntas que consideres necesario.
Con ello vas a poder desarrollar productos de calidad.

Comment: Sería mejor si dejas de utilizar una sintaxis obsoleta y la cambias por el estandar que existe desde 1992 con la expresión `JOIN`.

Comment: @LuisCazares , muchas gracias por escribir, su participación es valiosa. Creo que conocer varias formas de hacer lo mismo puede ser útil, para tener la capacidad de migrar el código a una mejor estructura cuando se considere necesario. Por favor puedes compartirnos cómo sería el cambio para este caso, donde las llaves foráneas y primarias son diferentes, como normalmente sucede cuando estás trabajando en procesos de integración a BDC (Bases de datos consolidada). Estaré muy atento a su participación.

Comment: @LuisCazares evita hacer cambios radicales en una respuesta que no es tuya.

Comment: yo pasaria de decir que la cosa no cambia mucho si cambias de base.. si cambia mucho si usas oracle por ejemplo... la respuesta no es mala, es muy completa, pero esta demasiado dirigida a crear algo,  y no a explicar el problema y su solucion...

Comment: @gbianchi Usualmente no lo hago, pero el autor de la respuesta lo solicitó.

Comment: @LuisCazares no entendi eso, si no que le dijeras que cambios proponias... por si acaso, evitalo en las respuestas... sobre todo si el cambio es tan radical...